# What does fn.id mean

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I have looked through DarkRP code to learn to create my own addons and game modes. I am trying to understand all that is happening and I have seen fn.id many times and fail to understand what it means. Anyone who can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it :)

Comment: `func = fp{fn.Id, true}` is equivalent to `func = function(...) return true, ... end`

Answer (score 0):

`fn.Id` is the identity function, from the `fn` module. It returns the arguments passed to it.

Comment: Okay thank you, have you got any resources I can read ?